# Using Verb in past tense with 'had better' in indirect narration

Tags: exam-questions, reported-speech, direct-speech

[image: verb form with had better]

This sentence is from an direct to indirect narration conversion exercise. As you can see the exercise has marked C as correct answer but I suspect it to be wrong as I never came across any sentence with structure *had better + past form of verb*, I googled and found sentences using only *had better+ verb form 1* so I think correct answer should be B, Am I correct or in indirect narration it's fine to use past form of verb ?

Comment: In my experience, I've never ever heard anyone say ***we had better did something***. I think what the book says is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**had better + {past participle}**  is rare in contemporary English, certainly American English, and speakers will avoid it, if they are even aware of it as an option, as few are:

> She said to Mr Weston that it would be better if they moved on. <sup>contemporary</sup>

By contrast, here's something from a work printed in London in 1845 (emphasis mine):

> The admiring pupil is perhaps not select in his gatherings and
>   recollections; he embalms much that **had better gone** to decay; he
>   accumulates rubbish as well as rubies; be possibly mistakes, or
>   mistates, the words or intentions of the speaker; and he injures the
>   fair fame of the object of his veneration, by recording much that **had
>   better been** forgotten...

Comment: Jane Austen, [Mansfield Park](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+had+better+have+gone+out+fanny%22): *You had better **have** gone out.* Suits me much better with that highlighted auxiliary verb included.

Comment: Yes, but the shade of meaning is different, I think. At the time, it would have been better to leave at that point (**had better gone**).  At the time, it would have been better to have left already (**had better have gone**).

Comment: I'm not completely convinced about that. I can see a difference in *You'd better **have** tidied your room before I get back* (where unquestionably ***have*** is "required"), and your cited 1845 example (where I think ***have*** is effectively "optional", even though I personally would prefer to include it).